# Hofstadter butterfly patterns in different honeycomb lattice structures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, quantum-hall-effect

Without loss of generality, we set vector potential $A=\left( -yB,0,0 \right)$. Here B is magnetic field. And due to Peierls substitution, $t_{ij}\rightarrow \exp \left( igaA_{r_j} \right) t_{ij}$, where g is coupling strength.
However, in different honeycomb lattice structures, there are different Hofstadter butterfly patterns.

[image: honeycomb structure A]

[image: Hofstadter butterfly A]

Then if we change another type of honeycomb lattice, we have:

[image: honeycomb structure B]

[image: Hofstadter butterfly B1]

[image: Hofstadter butterfly B2]

In these last two plots, we can see that beside the period $\frac{2\pi}{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}}$, there is another large $\frac{12\pi}{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}}$ period, which lead energy widths from large to small and large again. Nevertheless, this property does not exist in the first type of lattice structure. I hope to understand the reason on this exotic pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Your Hofstadter butterfly for nearest-neighbor hopping on the honeycomb lattice (first figure) is almost correct, however some aperiodicity remains in the spectrum. A common cause is using artificial Cartesian coordinates to construct the Harper equation, e.g. $(x,y) = (mb, nc)$, where $b=a/2$, $c=\sqrt{3}a/6$, and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. There are several ways that you can restore periodicity in the spectrum:

1. The simplest method is to multiply all of your flux densities by two (or some larger integer). This will yield two (or more) Hofstadter butterflies in the domain $0\leq n_\phi\leq1$ with the correct periodicity.
2. An incorrect method, but one that yields the correct visual result, is to use the approach of e.g. Oh in the paper "[Energy Spectrum of a Honeycomb Lattice under Nonuniform Magnetic Fields](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjm9LGKt-KCAxWwk2oFHUhuB0oQFnoECBYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jkps.or.kr%2Fjournal%2Fdownload_pdf.php%3Fspage%3D672%26volume%3D49%26number%3D2&usg=AOvVaw3rHtl7Cgi4sdyw5U9OxXvr&opi=89978449)" or "[Energy Spectrum of a Triangular Lattice in a Uniform Magnetic Field: Effect of Next-Nearest-Neighbor Hopping](https://www.jkps.or.kr/journal/view.html?volume=37&number=5&spage=534&year=2000)". In this case, you define the Bloch periodicity over $M = q$ $(2q)$ for even (odd) $p$, which yields exponential factors in the boundary terms of the Hamiltonian. This is incorrect because there are a different number of bands for even (odd) $p$, however, in the large $q$ limit the touching bands are indistinguishable and so the butterfly looks correct.
3. A correct method is to perform an explicit unitary transformation of the wavefunctions in the Schrödinger equation. This is sometimes known as a Rammal transformation and is given in Eq.4.7 of "[Landau level spectrum of Bloch electrons in a honeycomb lattice](https://hal.science/jpa-00210078/document)".
4. Finally, another correct method, and the one which I recommend because it is the most intuitive, is to write down simultaneous Schrödinger equations for the two basis sites, e.g.
   $$E \Psi_{m,n}^A = -t e^{\mathrm{i}\theta_1}\Psi_{m,n}^B -te^{\mathrm{i}\theta_2}\Psi_{m-1,n}^B - t e^{\mathrm{i}\theta_3}\Psi_{m,n-1}^B,$$
   $$E \Psi_{m,n}^B = -t e^{\mathrm{i}\theta_4}\Psi_{m+1,n}^A -te^{\mathrm{i}\theta_5}\Psi_{m,n+1}^A - t e^{\mathrm{i}\theta_6}\Psi_{m,n}^A,$$
   which you can write in $2\times 2$ matrix form,
   $$\begin{pmatrix} H^{AA} & H^{AB} \\ H^{BA} & H^{BB} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \Psi^A \\ \Psi^B \end{pmatrix} = E \begin{pmatrix} \Psi^A \\ \Psi^B \end{pmatrix},$$
   and then construct the $q\times q$ Harper equations for each block of this matrix with respect to the unit cells, which are fundamental quantities of the lattice. This will yield a $2q \times 2q$ matrix in total, which does not have periodicity issues in this case.

The Hofstadter butterfly for nearest-neighbor hopping on the honeycomb lattice, as well as for any combination of hoppings on any lattice, can be easily computed using the open-source Python package HofstadterTools (https://hofstadter.tools). In the package, you can run the following command in the code directory to benchmark your results:

```
python butterfly.py -lat honeycomb
```

Fixing the periodicity issue for the general case is also discussed in the [HofstadterTools documentation](https://hofstadter.tools/theory/model.html). Once you have fixed this periodicity, you should find that there is only one correct Hofstadter butterfly for nearest-neighbor hopping on the honeycomb lattice.

[image]